# Mostrar la fecha según se escribe en España

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla en Mysql en la que muestro los usuarios de mi web en php y una columna en la que quiero que ponga el momento del último login de tipo Datetime y que acepta nulos en MySql.
Me lo marcaba bien, pero con el año delante.
Busqué por internet y vi que se podía arreglar con el método Date_format:

```
$sql="SELECT u.id,u.name,u.username,u.user_level,u.status,date_format(u.last_login,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%I:%S') AS last_login,";
```

Más tarde, dentro de un foreach, la muestro así:

```
<td><?php echo $a_user['last_login']; ?></td>
```

Ahora al entrar en esa página me aparece el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect datetime value:
> '16/03/2024 15:47:28 pm' for column `sistema`.`users`.`last_login` at
> row 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\includes\database.php:28 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\includes\database.php(28): mysqli->query('UPDATE users SE...') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\includes\sql.php(111):
> MySqli_DB->query('UPDATE users SE...') #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\auth_v2.php(11): updateLastLogIn('1') #3
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\includes\database.php on line
> 28

He de decir que en la bbdd aparece el año primero y en la web, si actualizo la página del error, aparece la tabla con las fechas bien ordenadas.
Ya sé que en Mysql no se debe corregir las fechas, pero cómo puedo mostrarlas bien en mi web?

EDITO: En Mysql he realizado esta consulta y, al contrario que en la tabla, aparecen bien las fechas:

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,u.username,u.user_level,u.status,date_format(u.last_login,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%I:%S') AS last_login,g.group_name 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN user_groups g ON g.group_level=u.user_level ORDER BY u.name ASC
```

Por lo tanto, creo que el problema está en cómo ejecuto la muestra en mi web.

Comment: Lee bien el mensaje de error. Estás intentando una actualización en la base de datos con una fecha mal formateada, y eso es lo que provoca el error: `mysqli->query('UPDATE users SE...')` revisa el archivo `C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\includes\database.php` en la línea `28`. Sería ahí donde estarías intentando un `UPDATE`  con fecha no válida. Por otra parte, lo que afirmas aquí: *Ya sé que en Mysql no se debe corregir las fechas* es un grave error de concepto. No confundas **formatear** una fecha con **corregir** una fecha. Simplemente la BD por convención guarda las fechas empezando por el año.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hagas eso en la DB, hazlo cuando ya tengas los datos, con lo fácil que es formatear fechas con PHP. No cargues la DB de gusto!!!

```php
// Acá iria lo que traes de la DB
$originalDate = "2024-03-17";
echo $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($originalDate));

// Resultado => 17/03/2024
```